# Why does HTTP request to remote WebDriver server time out after 60 s despite commandTimeout of 120 s?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, browserstack

Using Selenium WebDriver on .NET, when testing a web application on Chrome on Android at BrowserStack, I occasionally get the error `OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds` even though I pass a `commandTimeout` to the driver that is longer:

```cs
new AndroidDriver(
    myUrl,
    myDriverOptions,
    commandTimeout: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
)
```

Other timeouts I have read about but do not set myself are:

- AsynchronousJavaScript - Default: 0:30
- ImplicitWait - Default: 0:00
- PageLoad - Default: 3:20

So there should not be any timeout of 60 seconds. Where does this come from? And what can I do to prevent it?

Unfortunately I do not get a proper stack trace, just this:

```
OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
  ----> System.TimeoutException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the culprit. It is a bug in *Appium.WebDriver 5.0.0-rc.1*. The `commandTimeout` I pass is ignored when the following constructor in class `OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver` (lines 77-80) is (indirectly) called:

```cs
public AppiumDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities appiumOptions, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
    : this(remoteAddress, appiumOptions, DefaultCommandTimeout, AppiumClientConfig.DefaultConfig())
{
}
```

In *Appium.WebDriver 5.0.0-rc.4* (or earlier) it has been fixed:

```cs
public AppiumDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities appiumOptions, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
    : this(remoteAddress, appiumOptions, commandTimeout, AppiumClientConfig.DefaultConfig())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are experiencing  ('The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.') is a known issue with C# selenium bindings and can be because of the following factors -
​
There is a 60 seconds timeout set for the RemoteWebDriver to receive a response for a request made. You can try increasing the timeout value to 120 seconds or 240 seconds and check whether that helps resolve your issue -

RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), capabilities);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

OR

RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), capability.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));

driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

Comment: Thanks, but these are the timeouts that I already mentioned.